# Using localstorage dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm brand new to react, so bare with me.

I have some data set in local storage before i start my react application, and i want to dynamically loop through local storage and display the data.

Currently I have it explicitly set:

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>locale: {localStorage.getItem('locale')}</li>
                <li>pubKey: {localStorage.getItem('pubKey')}</li>
                <li>version: {localStorage.getItem('version')}</li>
                <li>dist: {localStorage.getItem('dist')}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

but i want to not do explicit definitions, but loop through the localstorage data this dynamically.

elegant and complex solutions always welcome as well.

UPDATE::

I've tried:

in html:

```
<script>
window.localStorage.setItem('app:data:persist',JSON.stringify({"version":"0.0.1","dist":"shard","locale":"en_US","pubKey":"6asd68d68ddd6saadd79asd7das79ads9"}));</script></head>
<body>
```

```
const App = () => {
    const localStorageData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('app:data:persist'));
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <ul>
                {localStorageData.map((data,key) => {
                    return (
                        <li>{key} : {data[key]}</li>
                    )
                })};
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

but i cant get the value for the entry with the key correctly?

Comment: have you considered using redux? https://redux.js.org/

Comment: i updated the question. i want to loop through the local storage dynamically and display a list. ill look into redux, but id also like to know how to use this just for learning.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear about *handle this dynamically* and *explicit definitions*. Please clarify. If you use Redux, you can use https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist. Load the cached data into the redux store from the store engine when the application initializes.

If you don't want to use redux, just use one cache key for the whole cached data of the application.

Also, consider using React context to hold the cached data, so that nested components can access the cached data conveniently.

E.g.

```
localStorage.setItem('myapp:1.0.0:persist', JSON.stringify({ list, ... }));

const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myapp:1.0.0:persist'));
data.list.map(...)
```

Comment: can you see my updated question?

Comment: @somejkuser Where did you set the cache data?

Comment: @somejkuser Then make sure the script is loaded before the application bundle js